# include file(s) from another directory

Tags: php, file, include

Currently I am trying to `include` a PHP file from another directory.

```
public_html/a/class/test.php <-- from this file i would to include a file from
public_html/b/common.php <-- wanted to include this file
```

Not sure what I should do because I have tried using

```
dirname(__FILE__)
```

and this keeps on returning `public_html/a/` for me instead.

I have tried something like this

```
 dirname(__FILE__).'/../b/common.php'
```

but it does not help me in getting my file.

Comment: `dirname(__FILE__)` should be `public_html/a/class`, and if it is, you would need `dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../b/common.php'`

Comment: seems to be working..but wondering what does the /../ do?

Comment: FYI `__DIR__ === dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: Each `../` goes up one level. So if you start in `public_html/a/class`, you need to go up _two_ levels back to `public_html` to get to `/b`

Comment: If `public_html` is your `DOCUMENT_ROOT`, you could also do `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/b/common.php'`

Comment: tried $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] and seems to be returning /usr/local/apache/htdocs and i dont see public_html folder..

Answer (score 3):

You can simply keep moving up the directory tree until you have the common ancestor:

```
require dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/b/common.php';
```

The magic constant `__DIR__` equals `dirname(__FILE__)`, and was introduced in 5.3. Each use of `dirname()` goes back one directory, i.e.:

```
dirname('public_html/a/class'); // public_html/a
dirname('public_html/a'); // public_html
```

Btw, editors such as PhpStorm also understand this use of relative paths.

Comment: I'd advise to *never* rely on `DOCUMENT_ROOT`. For one, it isn't set in a non-web context (CLI, cron jobs, etc). Secondly, if the app is moved to a sub-directory, all paths become incorrect. Using a relative path from `__DIR__` is best

Comment: @Phil Fair enough, removed :)

Answer (score 0):

```
include('../../b/common.php');
```

would include file for you, make sure both directory have same usergroup as user.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i suggest you to define a variable for basepath and include that defined variable in relative files.

```
// This should be on any root directory file
define("PR_BASEPATH", dirname(__FILE__));
```

And according to your implementation, Assume you are in

```
public_html/a/class/test.php
```

and `dirname(__FILE__)` returns the directory name of the current file that always return the directory `class` according to `test.php` file.

And you want to include `public_html/b/common.php` that is on the other directory `/b`. So you have to get the document root directory first.

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/b/common.php";
```

Take a look on [$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php#111471)